# Downloading multiple (4<) PFFile's from parse and keeping them sync into their correct array

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

So I have a a username and a few FFile's from parse.com

Class) image class

- B) column: PFFile) imageOne
- C) column: PFFile) imageTwo
- D) column: PFFile) imageThree
- E) column: PFFile) imageFour
- F) column: PFFile) imageFive
- G) column: PFFile) imageSix

How can I download them together WHILE keeping them in their correct order or index within the array? The Asyncro really messes with me and I can't wrapp my head around it. Some images take longer than other.

I can use the

```
imageOne.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let imageOne = UIImage(data:imageData)
        self.imageOneArray.append(imageOne)
    }
}
//repeat
//imageTwo.getData...
//imageThree.getData...
//imageFour.getData...
//imageFive.getData...
...etc.
```

but what this does, is that it downloads them at different times due to the block which does it in the background. Then when I want to show them in my tableview. It's out of order.

What i've tried.
I've download the FFile then convert the NSData into UIImages in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but it's laggy because it's always converting the NSData into UIImage when I scroll up or down which is not a good experience.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to load all the images synchronously but concurrently using dispatch groups:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
let group = dispatch_group_create()

//////////////////////////////// Download block
dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> void in

// load your image here synchronously (use getData instead of getDataInBackgroundWithBlock) 
// then when you downloaded it, insert it at the correct array index
}
//////////////////////////////////
// repeat above block for each image you have

// wait for all of them to finish
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

// Here you can access your downloaded image array which must be in the correct order
```

Comment: thanks mate. I'll start by researching out what all those things means and how it works exactly. I'll make the simple changes and post my update. It should be simple enough because I'm DL'ing images. I'll get back to you within a few days. cheers!